# Chrome: How to make Chrome download to temp folder, then "move"?

Tags: google-chrome

Chrome seems to insist of downloading everything to some final location on my hard drive.

i would really prefer it to download to my temp folder, then do a "move" operation later.

This is especially required when i just want to "Open" the file (i.e. a .torrent), and then be done with the file.

How do I do this?

Comment: what do you mena by a "move" ?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365239(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically, Chromium downloads the file to the Cache directory (defaults to `%userprofile%\Local Settings\Application Data\…\Cache`), and then moves it to wherever you choose to save it.

What you could try is to leave the *Save As* dialog open until the transfer ends instead of clicking Save. Then you could run the file directly from your Cache directory (which is easy to clear), except that it will be unnamed so you’d have to find it—which isn’t really that hard since it will be the most recent file.

A better (and probably the currently easiest) solution is to simply have it auto-open .torrent files. Download one, then click the down-arrow of the file in the download bar and select **Always open files of this type**. That way, when you get the *Save As* dialog, you can just perpend `%temp%\` to the filename, and click Save. Then it would open the .torrent file and would be erased the next time you clear out your TEMP directory.

HTH

Comment: Technically you're right. i guess i should have phrased my question, "Download to temp, then move - if i ask it to."

Answer (score 1):

Tools->Options->Under the Hood->Download location: change to your temp folder

Comment: I guess you could have something monitor that folder and move any completed files somewhere else. Pretty specific requirements, but I'm sure a simple python script could handle it.

Comment: Chrome already downloads to a temp location be default: the cache folder.

Comment: Not all <i>that</i> specific. i'm trying to get it to behave like ie. i really hate that download bar.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking strictly for .torrent files, you can choose from the utorrent options to delete the torrent file after loading it.
See it at Options-Directory - check: Automatically load .torrents from... and Delete loaded .torrents....

Answer (score -1):

Just make Explorer you default, then open Chrome for your browser and click `don't show me this again` when it asks you if you want to make it your default. Now when I click a movie or whatever it opens in Explorer and doesn't go to my hard drive, but I still browse with Chrome.

Comment: -1:  No capitalization, insufficient punctuation, run-on sentence.  You know you can do better than this.

Comment: I suggest you read [answer] for help answering questions.